# How to convert double to int and display it on Text in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swiftui

I've created an Double variable and in the view it's displaying like "1.0" I just want to display it in "1" so how can I do conversion in text to display it.

```
Text("Here: \(Int(myViewModel.myModel.doubleValue.description))")
                        .font(.body)
```

When I add Int near I'm getting this error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47MbU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve all format like as below example

```
let doubleValue : Double = 5.33435

Text("\(String(format: "%.1f", doubleValue))") ---> 5.3
Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", doubleValue))") ---> 5.33
Text("\(String(format: "%.3f", doubleValue))") ---> 5.334
```

So, You can use String formating for this like as below

```
Text("Here: \(String(format: "%.0f", myViewModel.myModel.doubleValue))")
        .font(.body)
```

Here is output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but when I try this method it displaying number only 0. I'm using stepper to increase the value. but the value is not changing, its displaying only 0.

Comment: Make Sure that your model value changes on stepper click

Comment: yes, when it is on double, the value is changing

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake, I removed .descripton and its working perfectly! thank you soo much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Int()` initializer that takes a string can return a `nil` value if the string can't be converted. You just need to give it a default to fall back on, like:

```
Text("Here: \(Int(myViewModel.myModel.doubleValue.description) ?? 0)")
                        .font(.body)
```

Comment: Nice catch, I forgot the optional.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in an `Int`.

```
     // here! ↓
Text("Here: \(Int(myViewModel.myModel.doubleValue.description))")
                        .font(.body)
```

Comment: I've added like you said, but getting error. please check the edited version of my question